# HiddenField value lost

Tags: asp.net, hiddenfield

I'm having a very strange problem with our ASP.NET application. It is losing the value of a HiddenField on the pages that I had programmed. I will explain the situation in a simple way:

1. I have a page that has 4 Buttons and 1 HiddenField.
2. 3 of this buttons modify the value on the HiddenField.
3. The fourth button reads the value of the HiddenField, something like this:

```vb
    Select Case hf_PageState.Value
            Case "new"
                'Validate data only on new
                '...
            Case "modify", "delete"
                'Validate data only on modify or delete
                '...
            Case Else
                'Critic error
                Throw New Exception("HiddenField Value lost")
        End Select
```

This button is only available after using any of the 3 buttons mentioned before.

1. In very very strange cases, when the user uses the fourth button, the application fires the "HiddenField Value lost", but I don't know why, because after a lot of test I can't reproduce the problem. This problem has ocurred approximately every 3 months.

¿There is a way a HiddenField can lost their values assigned for any reason? This weird problem happened now on 2 pages with distinct logic function.

Comment: Keep in mind hidden fields (or any html) may be manipulated at client side before posting it to the server.

Comment: check the page_load event handler if you are setting the hidden field in case of post back's

Comment: @zed I know that scenario but users that had that problem are very basic users... they do not know how to do that. Thanks anyway

Comment: Can you try this - `Request["hf_PageState"]`.

Comment: Ok, if that's the case, verify every place where you are assigning a value to the hiddenfield, you may be missing something. Check client side code and server side code. Also, provide us more code of your scenario (.aspx file and .vb) so we can review it.